# C# Culture-Sensitive sentence identification

Tags: c#, localization, globalization

Is there a culture-sensitive way of identifying sentences in a string?

Or is there a something in the .NET framework (or elsewhere) that provides culture specific sentence terminators

For example where English uses say '.', '!', '?' (and others) to mark the end of sentences, Chinese uses 。 and Thai uses a space.

Comment: Yeah, go ahead and annoy 65 million French.  Of course this doesn't work.

Comment: @Hans: What exactly doesn't work? French has sentence separators just like other languages (identical to English ones, actually)

Comment: What underlying problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps we could offer alternate solutions if we knew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see how with stuff built into the framework.  One thing you could do is to make a series of parsers and choose the correct one based on CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.  That is, have a parser that implements a new interface called ISentenceParser and make a bunch of implementations that each handle sentence parsing according to a specific language.  Then, when you need to parse, you get the one needed for your language.

A better question, though, is why is this necessary?  I can think of very few situations where you would want to parse into sentences (though maybe I'm just not being creative enough :)).

Comment: Any kind of NLP programming... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing#Major_tasks_in_NLP

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. Following the NLP link this is the specific problem I was trying to understand. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_breaking. It was the end of a long day and Sentence breaking (as I shall hence forth refer to it) sounded like a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

i think that there is no such thing as end of sentence in dot net. so you have to use your own implementation of this. what are you trying to do?